# Avoid using type assertions in the branches of a type switch

Tags: go

I use type switches in Go, e.g. the following one:

```
switch question.(type) {
case interfaces.ComputedQuestion:
    handleComputedQuestion(question.(interfaces.ComputedQuestion), symbols)
case interfaces.InputQuestion:
    handleInputQuestion(question.(interfaces.InputQuestion), symbols)
}
```

Is there a way to prevent that I have to assert the type of question inside the case before I can pass it to another function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, assigning the result of the type switch will give you the asserted type

```
switch question := question.(type) {
case interfaces.ComputedQuestion:
    handleComputedQuestion(question, symbols)
case interfaces.InputQuestion:
    handleInputQuestion(question, symbols)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/qy0TPhypvp

Comment: Awesome Jim, two answers in a row. Knew there had to be a better way. Thanks so much!

Comment: @edwardmp, that's explained in [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements). "Effective Go" [has it covered](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) as well and so does [the wiki's article on switches](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Switch). So I really advise you do read a book on Go ("Effective Go" would be just okay for a start).