# Type Assertion Non Parsimonious

Tags: object, go, struct, types, assertion

I have the following, which works:

```
        reflectItem := reflect.ValueOf(dataStruct)
        subItem := reflectItem.FieldByName(subItemKey)
        switch subItem.Interface().(type) {
            case string:
                subItemVal := subItem.Interface().(string)
                searchData = bson.D{{"data." + 
                  strings.ToLower(subItemKey), subItemVal}}
            case int64:
                subItemVal := subItem.Interface().(int64)
                searchData = bson.D{{"data." + 
                  strings.ToLower(subItemKey), subItemVal}}
        }
```

The issue is that this seems very non-parsimonious. I would very much like to simply get the type of `subItem` without having a switch statement that simply asserts back its own type after finding the field by name. I'm not sure how to back this out however. Ideas?

Comment: You mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091801/avoid-using-type-assertions-in-the-branches-of-a-type-switch?

Comment: No - I don't want a switch statement at all - it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. That's the point of a "type switch", it is to conditionally assert over multiple possible types. You can get rid of the switch, or get rid of the individual assertions, but not both.

Comment: Hmm...well I want to grab the field *and the type* at once. It seems insane that I can't do that. Why can't I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following. `subItem` is a reflected value, and you can inspect the type as a `reflect.Type`, but that isn't a real type, and can only be used within reflection. Your example here however doesn't even need type assertions, because you're doing the same thing regardless of type, you can just put `subItem.Interface()` in `bson.D`.

Comment: I was about to say that, given the example code, dont type switch at all (https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#DocElem). for general case, a switch seems ok for this particular situation about basic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question exactly, but what you're doing can be easily shortened without affecting functionality:

```
    reflectItem := reflect.ValueOf(dataStruct)
    subItem := reflectItem.FieldByName(subItemKey)
    switch subItemVal := subItem.(type) {
        case string:
            searchData = bson.D{{"data." + 
              strings.ToLower(subItemKey), subItemVal}}
        case int64:
            searchData = bson.D{{"data." + 
              strings.ToLower(subItemKey), subItemVal}}
    }
```

But beyond that, I don't think a type assertion is necessary in your case *at all*.  This should also work:

```
    reflectItem := reflect.ValueOf(dataStruct)
    subItem := reflectItem.FieldByName(subItemKey)
    searchData = bson.D{{"data."+strings.ToLower(subItemKey), subItem.Interface())
```

Comment: Sorry guys I got myself confused. I'm still not totally used to strictly typed languages. Thanks for the replies.